# Асинхронный сервер на python и библиотеке asyncio, почему функция recv блокирует при наличии await?

Tags: python, asyncio

Кодил асинхронный сервер на asyncio, может не до конца понял концепцию асинхронного программирования, но столкнулся с проблемой, что не принимает второе подключение клиента, хотя вроде как event_loop должен в цикле постоянно переключаться между этими функциями, все тормозится на user.recv(2048), клиентская сторона обычная, подскажите, что не так сделано?

```
import asyncio
import time
from Socket import Socket

class Server(Socket):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Server, self).__init__()

        self.bind(("127.0.0.1", 1279))

        self.listen(5)

        self.users = []

    def main(self):

        func = [
            asyncio.ensure_future(self.create_socket()),
            asyncio.ensure_future(self.receive_message())
        ]

        ioloop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

        while True:

            ioloop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*func))

    async def create_socket(self):

        print("create socket")

        await self.receive_message()

        user_socket, user_address = self.accept()

        print(user_socket)

        self.create_user_socket(user_socket)

        return user_socket, user_address

    def create_user_socket(self, user_socket):
        self.users.append(user_socket)

        print(self.users)

    async def receive_message(self):
        for user in self.users:
            print("receive")
            print(asyncio.gather)
            data = await user.recv(2048)
            print(f"User sent")

server = Server()
server.main()
```

Comment: Потому что функция recv всегда была, есть и будет блокирующей, и никакой await не способен это изменить. И функция accept кстати тоже

Comment: Если вы хотите асинхронную работу с сетью, то используйте соответствующий асинхронный интерфейс https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html

Comment: разве не asyncio со своим EventLoop с помощью await останавливает выполнение корутины и передает управление менджеру событий? это и есть реализация парадигмы асинхронного программирования

Comment: Вот именно что он останавливает **корутины**, а функция recv никогда не была и не будет корутиной (и функция accept тоже)

Comment: не знаю, но по-моему этот парень думает иначе https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CnEYB9pjs9o

Comment: Я не собираюсь смотреть полчаса какой-то скучной болтовни, но код у него лютая непотребная дичь. Подозреваю, что этот парень совершенно не разбирается в асинхронщине.

Comment: От этого функция не перестанет быть блокирующей. Перестаньте смотреть каких-то глупых парней и обратитесь к [официальной документации Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html), которая всё пишет правильно и по-настоящему асинхронно

Comment: Здесь я с тобой согласен, на ютюбе нет годности по этому направлению